# MyBatis: "Compile-time" mapper params replacement, keeping prepared stmt but making table names configurable?

Tags: ibatis, mybatis, prepared-statement

MyBatis 3.1.1 allows either #{...} for prepared statements params,
or ${...} for every-time replacement.

I am missing something what would allow to parametrize parts of the SQL statement but still keep it prepared statement; i.e. replace during configuration.

How can I do that? Maybe using some SQL fragments?

**Update:**

I found:

```
<sql id="userColumns"> id,username,password </sql>
<select id="selectUsers" parameterType="int" resultType="hashmap">
    SELECT <include refid="userColumns"/> some_table WHERE id = #{id}
</select>
```

See http://www.mybatis.org/core/sqlmap-xml.html#sql
This would be it if `${...}` could be used inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found it...

```
<sql id="userColumns"> id,username,password </sql>
```

And then

```
<select id="selectUsers" parameterType="int" resultType="hashmap">
    SELECT <include refid="userColumns"/>
    FROM some_table
    WHERE id = #{id}
</select>
```

So I will use ${...} in that and that should get me there.

See http://www.mybatis.org/core/sqlmap-xml.html#sql

Comment: So, this turned not to work - `${...}` is simply kept as is and expanded when the SQL fragment is used.

Answer (score 1):

in my project we have a very simple solution for this case.

We have a String called TABLENAME in the Data Objects.
When we construct the Objects we initialize the tablename.
and in the sqls we have the tablename enquoutet.

in the DataObject:

```
String TABLENAME;
public String getTABLENAME() {return TABLENAME;}
public void setTABLENAME(String tablename) {this.TABLENAME = TABLENAME;}
```

in the sqls:

```
<delete id="simpleDelete" parameterClass="Integer">
    delete from ${jdbc.schema}.$TABLENAME$ 
    WHERE ID = #ID#
</delete>
```

I don't know if this is the best solution, but it works quite well. I am open for better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Since `<sql>` doesn't work as needed for this purpose, I filled a feature request.
http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/issues/detail?id=627